# Prevent responsive design to kick in when zooming

Tags: html, css

Hy, i would appreciate some help with zooming/responsive design on my web site. Basically, i would like to know why does my site, and how to disable it - when zooming in, redelegates divs according to media queryies. I would like to media query kick in only on browser/screen resize, not on zoom. Heres my outline code:

```css
    body {
  background-image: url(../img/Fotolia.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #464646;
  font-family: "Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  max-width: 100%;
 }
 
 .container {
  padding: 20px 20px 30px 20px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  max-width: 1300px;
  text-align: justify;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f3f3f3;
 }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1350px) {
        some stuff
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1090px) {
        some stuff
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
        some stuff
    }
```

```html
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="left">
                </div>

                <div class="right">
                </div>
            </div>
```

When zooming the browser to 150%, 1350px kicks in, on 180% zoom 1090 kicks in, and so on. How can i disable responsive design on zooming ? thx.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a meta tag to disable zooming? As far as I know, there is no way to stop responsiveness when zooming.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Comment: Hm, not really my intention to disable zooming completly

Comment: Then you have no real alternative @Greedy

Answer (score 0):

When the user zooms, they ask the browser to make each pixel bigger.

Since the pixels are bigger, fewer of them can fit in the window.

This changes the width and thus the max-width @media rules that apply.

You can't prevent this.